# Vim wizardry to do this

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

Want a simple way to create this file:

```
def foo1():

def foo2():

def foo...():

def fooN():
```

without typing each function signature out. Possible? In excel I would make 'def foo' a column, make an integer column, then a '():' column, copy paste into a .py file, but I want an equally simple solution in vim or sublime! Anyone know how to do this sorcery?

Comment: With the `...` do you mean same things for the other numbers or it is taken literally ?

Comment: I meant for all 3 - (N-1), could have been better written, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this trick, we'll use vim. Start by typing the first definition at the top of the code. In insert mode type:

`def foo1():`

Then exit insert mode using `<esc>`.

We'll now create a vim macro to replicate this as many times as you like. Go to the beginning of the file with `gg`.

Now, start [recording a macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros#Recording_a_macro) using `qq`. This will store your macro in the "q" register. First make a copy of the function definition using `yyp`. If you want, you can create a blank line above using `O<esc>j`. Then [increment](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Increasing_or_decreasing_numbers) the function number of your copy using `Ctrl + a`. Finish by going to the beginning of the line using `0` and stop recording the macro using `q`.

Now simply replay the macro as many times as you like. For example, type `100@q` to play it 100 times. Voilà!

Comment: ooooo wow thats great, very impressed with your knowledge! I extended this solution a little, too, for when the function bodies are identical. If the function is # lines long, replace yyp with y#y, shift+g, p. THANKS!

Comment: I would personally follow the macro approach but there're always 100 ways to do the same thing in vim. U could  for example use custom snippet in UltiSnips and feature called python interpolation to always have that snippet at hand - for later usage.

Answer (score 3):

Change the value of the variable `N` to your needs:

```
:let N=5
:execute "normal! ".N."idef foo0():\r\r\<Esc>" | g/\d\+/ :.,$s//\=submatch(0)+1/
```

---

`N` *denotes the number of `foo` functions starting from `1` to `N`*

Comment: Wow that's great! This is a really dense line of code... i'll be visiting the docs to see what all this stuff means. Thanks!

Comment: You can just copy and paste or add a map. You will notice also that there is a teeny-weeny trick in the substitution command to increment the number of the function ! If you did not get it feel free to ask :)